# PHP PDO Procedure

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, procedure

I couldn't find the error in this Code. Can anyone help?

```
$stmt = $DB->prepare("CALL dbo.HisIsTheProcedureName(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam( 1, $_POST['Val01'], PDO::PARAM_STR,8000);
$stmt->bindParam( 2, $_POST['Val02'], PDO::PARAM_STR,8000);
$stmt->bindParam( 3, $_POST['Val03'], PDO::PARAM_STR,8000);
$stmt->execute();
```

After using debugDumpParams(), the following Dump is shown:

```
SQL: [30] CALL dbo.InsertFeedback(?,?,?)
Params:  3
Key: Position #0:
paramno=0
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #1:
paramno=1
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Position #2:
paramno=2
name=[0] ""
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

I don't get any Syntax or PHP errors.

Comment: Help with __what__? Follow [mcve] and update your question.

Comment: Note, with a PDO wrapper like [GrumpyPDO](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/GrumpyPDO), your entire query would be `$DB->run("CALL dbo.HisIsTheProcedureName(?,?,?)", [$_POST['Val01'], $_POST['Val02'], $_POST['Val03']]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `PDOStatement::bindParam()` except in very special circumstances. Just pass the parameters to `PDOStatement::execute()` instead. As for your question, it's possible you're missing some POST values. Ensure you're passing valid strings to the query, and check your return values.

```
$val01 = $_POST["Val01"] ?? "";
$val02 = $_POST["Val02"] ?? "";
$val03 = $_POST["Val03"] ?? "";

$stmt = $DB->prepare("CALL dbo.HisIsTheProcedureName(?,?,?)");
if ($stmt) {
    $result = $stmt->execute([$val01, $val02, $val03]);
    if (!$result) {
        //look at error messages
    }
} else {
    // look at error messages
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use named placeholders (:name) or question mark placeholders (?) with 1-indexed position of the parameter in `bindParam()`.

What you may try in your case is to remove length parameter in `bindParam()` call, if your parameters are input only.

```
$stmt = $DB->prepare("CALL dbo.HisIsTheProcedureName(?,?,?)");
$val01 = $_POST['Val01'];
$val02 = $_POST['Val02'];
$val03 = $_POST['Val03'];
$stmt->bindParam(1, $val01, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $val02, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $val03, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

If you have output parameters, then according to documentation, use this:

```
$val01 = $_POST['Val01'];
$val02 = $_POST['Val02'];
$val03 = $_POST['Val03'];
$stmt = $DB->prepare("CALL dbo.HisIsTheProcedureName(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $val01, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 8000);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $val02, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 8000);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $val03, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 8000);
$stmt->execute();
```